# Calculating Time Until a Future Date - Trouble With Formatting Date Correctly In Variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the time between now (any time user runs script) and daylight savings (Nov 03, 2019, 2:00 AM).

I think I'm close but am having trouble getting the date variables to format and interact properly. What would the right definition for the variable `dateTime` be, or am I messing up with the variable `daylightDate`?

```
function daylightTime()
{
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = "Current Date and Time: " +dateTime;

var daylightDate = new Date("November 03, 2019 02:00:00");

var delta = Math.abs(daylightDate  - dateTime) / 1000;
// calculate (and subtract) whole days
var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
delta -= days * 86400;
// calculate (and subtract) whole hours
var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
delta -= hours * 3600;
// calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
delta -= minutes * 60;
// what's left is seconds
var seconds = delta % 60;  // in theory the modulus is not required

document.getElementById("time2").innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;

}
```

Comment: there is typo. U cant just minus date. convert date to timestamp. var delta = Math.abs(daylightDate.getTime()  - new Date(dateTime).getTime()) / 1000;

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!